# Angular ui-router named views abstract controller not fireing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

It seems that having a controller in an abstract named view will not fire that controller when a child view also implements a controller, only the child controller fires. My setup is as follows:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        views : {
          header: {
            template: "<p>My header</p>"
          },
          section: {
            template: "<ui-view />",
            controller: function () {
              alert('loaded main control');
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.home', {
        url: '',
        views: {
          'section@': {
            template: "<p> My initial content here </p>",
            controller: function () {
              alert("loaded home control");
            }
          }
        }
      })
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WjUYwEfrNbZrdpUQAole?p=preview

In my mind the above demo should trigger both alerts, why is this not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `app.home` you are using the `section@` as the view name, which is an absolute match, and then is conflicting with the `section` view defined in the abstract `app` state.

In fact, the first `section` view appears to be useless. You can try the following snippet.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    views : {
      header: {
        template: "<p>My header</p>",
        controller: function () {
          alert("loaded main control");
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.home', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      'section@': {
        template: "<p> My initial content here </p>",
        controller: function () {
          alert("loaded home control");
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

More details available in the [*Multiple Named Views* section of the ui-router guide.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: Well the point was that general section control should not reside in the header namespace, and if I should ever want to implement a header subview with a controller, then main control would silently not trigger...

Comment: The issue is just that you are refering to the same ui-view twice, hence the conflict. You have to refactor you application a bit for it to work. See [this updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lcu1f1v3YzMqsRt69EJs?p=preview)